# Javascript Reg Ex to match relative units

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match the part of a string expressing relative (arbitrary) units. For example "+=50foo", "-=300bar", "-3%". I'm mostly there but I'm getting weird errors for some inputs and I don't see the pattern or the fix.

```
var myRegEx = new RegExp( "^([+-])=(\\d+\.?\\d*)(\\D+)$", "i" );

console.log(myRegEx.exec("-=5%")); // good
console.log(myRegEx.exec("+=3.14wigs")); // good
console.log(myRegEx.exec("+=50px")); // broken: "50p", "x"
console.log(myRegEx.exec("+=49999999px")); // broken: "49999999p", "x"
console.log(myRegEx.exec("+=100em")); // broken: "100e" , "m"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sNd9W/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sNd9W/1/    var myRegEx = /^([+-])=([\d.]+)(.+)$/i;

Comment: Just use a literal regex, don't need the constructor and escaping everything twice that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cleaner solution:

```
var myRegEx = /^([+-])=(\d+\.?\d*)(\D+)$/i;
```

Your solution did not correctly double escape the period (you had \., needs \\.) because of the double quoted string doing its own escaping. To make things simpler, I didn't use a string at all.

Example in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/sNd9W/2/

Comment: The RegExp is the same as yours, only in C# or Java.

Answer (score 1):

This should work (note additional `\` near the dot):

```
var myRegEx = new RegExp( "^([+-])=(\\d+\\.?\\d*)(\\D+)$", "i" );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var myRegEx = /^([+-])=([\d.]+)(.+)$/i;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sNd9W/3/

First capture group is the +/-
Second is the numeric and decimal group
Last whatever was left over.

Comment: This would accept multiple decimals, passing "+=12.12.12.12em" or "+=.em"

Comment: You're right.  I was assuming that he would be parsing valid numbers.